# How to redirect a POST request to a specific view

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx

There is some service that sends a POST request to our CRM, but it sends a request to the root url `example.com`

How do I redirect all requests from this service to a specific url `example.com/webhooks/notifications/`

Perhaps using nginx? or what other options? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can use Nginx as reverse proxy in order to redirect requests to any url of your choice.

This tutorial might be what you need :

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/